# É possível ter um botão redondo sem alterar o atributo android:background?

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho no diretório `res>drawable>fundo.xml` o seguinte código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"></solid>
</shape>
```

Onde defino no `android:background="@drawable/fundo"` do `xml` do botão `res>layout>minha_lista.xml`:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/botao_alunos"
  android:text="+"
  android:textSize="15sp"
  android:textColor="#fff"
  android:layout_width="56dp"
  android:layout_height="56dp"
  android:background="@drawable/fundo"
/>
```

Para deixá-lo com formato arredondado à seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, o que me deixa um pouco confuso é alterar o atributo `background` e mudar também o seu formato, acredito que o que me deixa confuso é tentar associar esse atributo background a estilização *front-end*(coisa que não deveria fazer), mas me surgiu uma dúvida:

Há alguma maneira de evitar o uso do fundo.xml como background do botão e apenas usando os atributos do Button pudesse ser realizado a mesma mudança de seu shape?

Comment: nao seria melhor usar um Floating Action Button?

Comment: Consigo arredondá-lo com o Floating ActionScript Button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Há alguma maneira de evitar o uso do fundo.xml como background do botão e apenas usando os atributos do Button pudesse ser realizado a mesma mudança de seu shape?

Não.

Um botão, como qualquer View, é um rectângulo. Ele ocupará sempre uma área rectangular cujas dimensões são as definidas em `android:layout_width` e `android:layout_height`.

O que a View "mostra" nessa rectângulo, no caso de um Button, é o Drawable indicado através de `android:background`. O formato não é alterado, ele será sempre um rectângulo.

É possível usar/criar um outro tipo que derive de Button ou ImageButton(como é o caso do FloatingActionButton<sup>(1)</sup>), no entanto será sempre o conteúdo do seu `android:background` ou `android:src`, no caso do segundo, que dará a "forma"(aspecto) ao botão.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup>Um FloatingActionButton não é um botão redondo. Ele só será redondo se o Drawable indicado em `android:src` tiver uma "forma" redonda.</sub>

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda @ramaral!

Answer (score 0):

Um botão de ação flutuante (FAB) é um botão circular que aciona a ação principal na interface do usuário do seu aplicativo. Esta página mostra como adicionar o FAB ao seu layout, personalizar algumas de suas aparências e responder aos toques de botão.

Para saber mais sobre como criar um botão de ação flutuante em seu aplicativo de acordo com as diretrizes de material design: https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Adicione o botão de ação flutuante ao seu layout**

O código a seguir mostra como o `FloatingActionButton` deve aparecer no seu arquivo de layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
    android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Por padrão, o FAB é colorido pelo `colorAccent`, que você pode personalizar com a paleta de cores do tema.

Você pode configurar outras propriedades do FAB usando os atributos XML ou os métodos correspondentes, como os seguintes:

O tamanho do FAB, usando o `app:fabSize` pelo xml ou pelo método `setSize()`.

A cor de ondulação da FAB, usando o `app:rippleColor` pelo xml ou pelo método `setRippleColor()`.

O ícone FAB, usando o `android:src` pelo xml ou pelo método `setImageDrawable()`.

Comment: Bacana cara, vou dar uma olhada mais tarde. Beleza?

Comment: @AndréFilipe Note que um FloatingActionButton não é um botão redondo. Ele só será redondo se o Drawable indicado em `android:src` tiver uma "forma" redonda.

Comment: Bem lembrado, só notei isso agora pouco na hora da implementação. Por si só ele não é redondo... Muito obrigado @ramaral, esclareceu muito minhas dúvidas!